# wrong dependency_libs in .la file after make install with DESTDIR flag

Tags: make, configure

I am maintaining a locally-compiled version of [gpg](https://gnupg.org/download/). The end result is supposed to be a standalone suite of packages living in `/opt/local` (with the standard tree under that base directory: `usr/bin` for binaries, `usr/lib` for libraries, etc.).

As part of the installation process, I

- configure, compile and install `libgpg-error` in a temporary directory with

```
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/usr/lib" CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/usr/include" ./configure --prefix=/usr

MAKEFLAGS="-j4" DESTDIR=~/Downloads/tmp/libgpg-error make install
```

- make a Slackware package out of that directory and install it to `/opt/local`, resulting in the above-mentioned directory tree structure with executables in `/opt/local/bin`, etc.
- configure, compile and install `libgcrypt` in a temporary directory, as previously, this time taking into account that it depends on the previously-installed `libgpg-error` (hence the extra option passed to `./configure`):

```
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/usr/lib" CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/usr/include" ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-libgpg-error-prefix=/opt/local/usr

MAKEFLAGS="-j4" DESTDIR=~/Downloads/tmp/libgcrypt make install
```

Since `libgcrypt` depends on `libgpg-error`, the `make install` step on the former produces an `.la` file

`~/Downloads/tmp/libgcrypt/usr/lib/libgcrypt.la`

containing the following dependency line:

```
# Libraries that this one depends upon.
dependency_libs=' -L/opt/local/usr/lib /usr/lib/libgpg-error.la'
```

**The issue:**

Now, when I compile and try to install `ntbtls`, which is aware of both of the above packages, it

- reads `/opt/local/usr/lib/libgcrypt.la`
- sees the dependency on `/usr/lib/libgpg-error.la`, and
- tries to read that file, which doesn't exist, resulting in an error.

Everything goes through fine if I change that `dependency_libs` line to

```
# Libraries that this one depends upon.
dependency_libs=' -L/opt/local/usr/lib /opt/local/usr/lib/libgpg-error.la'
```

---

I've resorted to doing that manually (well, via a small script), but there must be some way around this through options I can pass to `./configure`. One reason I think that is that in the `libgcrypt` source directory, after running the `make install` command, I have both

- an `.lai` file (note the `i`) that reads as above (wrong dependency) and is transported to the resulting `.la` file in `DESTDIR`
- an `.la` file that has precisely the `dependency_libs` line I want:

```
diff <source_dir>/src/.libs/libgcrypt.la <source_dir>/src/.libs/libgcrypt.lai
```

returns

```
20c20
< dependency_libs=' -L/opt/local/usr/lib /opt/local/usr/lib/libgpg-error.la'
---
> dependency_libs=' -L/opt/local/usr/lib /usr/lib/libgpg-error.la'
31c31
< installed=no
---
> installed=yes
```

I am not familiar with the inner workings of `libtool` and don't know why the `/opt/local` is lost somewhere during the installation process resulting in this distinction between the two files (`.la` vs `.lai`).

I haven't found [much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109092/what-is-libtools-lai-file-for) discussion of `.lai` files at all, let alone more abstruse topics on how or when they're produced, but I'd like to understand that process in the hope of somehow hacking it for this specific purpose.

**What I've tried:**

Changing the `--prefix` or `--libdir` flags aren't really good options, because they result in a mangled directory structure for the installed packages under `/opt/local`.

Answer (score 1):

To arrive at the end result I believe you're describing, the only method I'm aware of that could produce it is to copy your dependencies into `/opt/local` (consistent with the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html)) and copy the source code into a temporary build directory there as well, after which you could chroot into `/opt/local` and run the `configure` script with `--prefix=""`.

Referring back to the FHS for a minute though, I believe your difficulties would be much reduced if you found a way to adapt the output of a build with `--prefix=/usr/local` to your purposes.